# Cluttered map on ME 2

Tags: mass-effect-2

My current Mass Effect Galaxy looks like the following:

[image]

The maps in ME1 and 3 were beter IMO
Is there a way to remove all the labels and clutter either in-game or through an INI file or some third party tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to clean up your galaxy map in Mass Effect 2 with all of the downloadable content installed (as you clearly have above) would be to quickly go and scan all of the planets marked with minerals on them - these are adding up the bulk of the excess on your screenshot and won't take any time at all to clear (just planet scanning).

In the screenshot above, these are marked as the following;

- Eezo Rich Planet
- Iridium Rich Planet
- Palladium Rich Planet
- Platinum Rich Planet

I do not believe there is any other method of 'cleaning up' the galaxy map other than actually completing each thing listed on the map.

Comment: I'm not sure, I always scan them to 'depleted' - shouldn't take too long to reach that state anyway